# Dynamic LINQ function using dictionary as a Parameter to filter method

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, func

I am new to the reflection area. I am have to filter a list of entity that has a dictionary by using it's key and value like below

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> SecQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

below extension is available in a dll and could not be modified

```
public static class extensions
{
    public static List<Person> FilterMe(this List<Person> Persons, Func<Person,bool> predicate)
    {
        // Logic to filter the persion list
        return Persons;
    }
}
```

hence I have to call the above method by using below code

```
persons.FilterMe(xy => xy.SecQuestions.Any(x => x.Key == "PlaceOfBirth" && x.Value == "Madurai"));
```

I need to know how to create

```
xy => xy.SecQuestions
    .Any(x => x.Key == "PlaceOfBirth" && x.Value == "Madurai")
```

dynamically using expression builders to pass as the parameter to the extension method. Thanks

Comment: Checking if a dictionary contains a specific KV-pair is best done by calling `myDictionary[key] == value` (can be complemented with a `myDictionary.ContainsKey(key)`). Using a `Where` call is quite frankly just plain weird and not how the dictionary class is supposed to be used.

Comment: Expression building is not reflection. Expressions are representation of the code that has been written.

Comment: Just to clarify, what part needs to be dynamic? Just the values your are searching for (i.e. `"PlaceOfBirth"` and `"Madurai"`) or also the properties  you are searching against?

Comment: The param for the extension method has to be dynamic. I need to compile the param xy => xy.SecQuestions
    .Any(x => x.Key == "PlaceOfBirth" && x.Value == "Madurai") which can be used for other entities of type string and int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var personP = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "xy");            // Creates xy Parameter
var SecQuestionsProp = Expression.Property(personP, "SecQuestions"); // Creates xy.SecQuestions

var anyMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.IsGenericMethod) // Search for Any methods...
    .Select(m => new {
                        Method = m,
                        Params = m.GetParameters(),
                        Args = m.GetGenericArguments()
                     })
    .Where(x => x.Args.Length == 1 
        && x.Params.Length == 2 
        && x.Params[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(x.Args)
        && x.Params[1].ParameterType == typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { x.Args.First(), typeof(bool) })) // Get the one defined as Any<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, bool>)
    .Select(x => x.Method)
    .First();

var keyValuePairP = Expression.Parameter(typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>), "x"); // Creates x Parameter
var KeyProp = Expression.Property(keyValuePairP, "Key");                             // Creates x.Key
var keyComparisonValue = Expression.Constant("PlaceOfBirth");                        // Creates the value that will be compared to x.Key
var keyComparison = Expression.Equal(KeyProp, keyComparisonValue);                   // Creates the comparison (x.Key == "PlaceOfBirth")

var ValueProp = Expression.Property(keyValuePairP, "Value");                         // Creates x.Value
var valueComparisonValue = Expression.Constant("Madurai");                           // Creates the value that will be compared to x.Value
var valueComparison = Expression.Equal(ValueProp, valueComparisonValue);             // Creates the comparison (x.Value == "Madurai")

var anyPredicate = Expression.Lambda(Expression.AndAlso(keyComparison, valueComparison), new ParameterExpression[] { keyValuePairP }); // Creates x => x.Key == "PlaceOfBirth" && x.Value == "Madurai"

var filterMeMethod = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>
    (Expression.Call(anyMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>) })
                    , new Expression[] { SecQuestionsProp, anyPredicate })
     , personP);  //Creates xy => xy.SecQuestions.Any(x => x.Key == "PlaceOfBirth" && x.Value == "Madurai")

var r1 = persons.FilterMe(filterMeMethod.Compile());  // Calls FilterMe with xy => xy.SecQuestions.Any(x => x.Key == "PlaceOfBirth" && x.Value == "Madurai") as parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any need at all here for using expression builders, or indeed any extension method (it seems like you are reinventing the wheel). Something like the following should suit your needs:

```
var filteredPeople = people.Where(person => person.SecQuestions[key] == value);
```

How `key` and `value` are determined is up to you. It could be method parameters or user input or whatever.

Comment: the extension method is in a dll, I need to create the expression to pass as a parameter. I could not modify the extension method as it is being used everywhere not only for the dictionary but also for all of the entity members like "Address", "PersonnelInfo".

Comment: But why do you need to use the extension method? If all it does is filtering a list, what is the point of it? Does it do something more than just applying the filter on the given list? If so, it's really badly named and does something different than what it's name says. I'm also confused as to what you mean by dynamically building the filter expression. Why won't it work to just send the Func as a lambda?

Comment: the business logic is meant for conversion of the entity from the web API; Hence expression is more important than filter myself

Answer (score 0):

If you **only** need the values you are comparing against to be dynamic then you could let the language to the heavy lifting:

```
public Expression BuildComparison(string key, string value)
{
    return Expression<Func<Person, bool>> exp = 
                 x => x.SecQuestions.Any(y => y.Key == key && y.Value == value);
}
```

Apologies if I have misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: no worries. But I need to compile the param for the extension method dynamically and not only for the dictionary but also for other entities present in the Person class like "Name", "Age"; I could able to do for type of string and int, but in the case of dictionary I could not able to compile...